# how do I update mysqli column names dynamically

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have 10 columns in a mysql database that I would like to call with a function.  The names of the columns are;
videoSec1,
videoSec2,
videoSec3,
videoSec4,
etc.  Can the statement be set with a variable?  The example that I came up with is not working.

```
$stmt1 = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE users SET ("videoSec"+index)=? WHERE userID=?);
$stmt1->bind_param('ii',$secc,$userID);
$stmt1->execute();
```

Comment: What you're looking for is a one-to-many relation.

Comment: Guess its not going to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create another table `videoSec`, consists of 2 columns: `index` and `userID`

And instead of updating it, just add or remove rows:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO videoSec SET index=?, userID=?');
$stmt->bind_param('ii',$secc,$userID);
$stmt->execute();
```

this is how relational database works.